# Accordion with increasing widths

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jQuery accordion on my site with all tabs open

What I want is for the width of the closed tabs (when it is closed) to increase in the order that it is closed

**Example here**
[image]

What I want to happen is that if there are 10 tabs and only the first 2 are closed, tab1 width should be 95% & tab2 should be 100%. 
If tab 3 is closed, tab1 width=90%, tab2=95% & tab3=100%.

Here's what I've tried:

I have added a jQuery which toggles a class `closed` to the closed tab & have tried using the `nth-last-child` to that for example

```css
.tab.closed:nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 100%
}

.tab.closed:nth-last-child(2) {
  width: 95%
}
```

But what is happening is that pseudo class is appending itself to the tab's main class & not just to the tabs with the `closed` class.

Is this method logical?
Or is there some better way to do this?

**Edit: Added a snippet below.**

```js
$('.panel-title a').click(function() {
  if ($('.collapse').hasClass('in')) {
    $(this).closest('.panel.panel-white').toggleClass("open");
    $(this).closest('.panel.panel-white').toggleClass("closed");
  }
});
```

```css
.panel.panel-white .panel-heading {
  background: #0769AD;
}

.panel.panel-white .panel-heading a {
  color: white
}

.closed:nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 80%;
}

.closed:nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel-group content-group-lg">
  <div class="panel panel-white open">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h6 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-group1">Collapsible Item #1</a>
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-group1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-white closed">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h6 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-group2">Collapsible Item #2</a>
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-group2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Тon cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Тesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-white closed">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h6 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-group3">Collapsible Item #3</a>
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-group3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /basic collapsible -->
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create a [mcve] in the question otherwise your question is off topic for SO and will be closed:
Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: Sorry, did not know that. Anyway, I think the question works without the link and is universal enough, so I removed the link & reframed it a bit

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: No, not really. The problem still stands.

Comment: Van you create a [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) snippet? It will make it easier for us to play with your code and understanding what is the solution.

Comment: Added one now. Please check if this is ok

Comment: It seems working. The last tab is `80%` just like you defined in the code. What's the issue?

Comment: I want the last closed tab to be smaller. If you close the first 2 & open the last one, by the css logic, the 2nd one should be smaller, but that's not happening. Check the image I've posted. That should help clear things up.